# c++: two pointers pointing to the same object share the same address?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a simple trial with pointers.

Both k1 and k2 are pointers and are pointing to j.

I somehow expect k1 and k2 are different. But on the other hand, if they are just representing the address of integer j, they should be the same.

Anyone can educate me what is the difference then between k1 and k2 if there is any?

```
int j=0, *k1=&j, *k2=&j;
j=2;
std::cout<<"k1 points to  "<<*k1 << " and k2 points to  "<<*k2 <<std::endl;
std::cout<<" k1 is "<< k1 << " k2 is "<<k2<<std::endl;
return 0;
```

But the result is showing

```
k1 points to  2 and k2 points to  2
k1 is 0x7fffffffd6fc k2 is 0x7fffffffd6fc
```

Comment: `std::cout << &k1` and `std::cout << &k2` will show you some difference that you seem to look for.

Comment: Why start with pointers? `int x=42, y=42;` Are x and y the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage for the variables `k1` and `k2` themselves are different. Their *values* (i.e. where they point) is the same. You could accomplish the same by simple assignment:

```
int j = 0;
int *k1, *k2;

k1 = &j;  // Make k1 point to the location of j
k2 = k1;  // Copy the value from k1 into k2, after this k2 also points to the location of j
```

If you want to print the location of the variables `k1` and `k2` you need to use the address-of operator `&`:

```
std::cout << "k1 is located at "<< &k1 << ", and k2 is located at "<< &k2 << std::endl;
```

---

In memory it *might* look something like this:

```
+-------------+
| variable j  | <--+--\
+-------------+    |  |
| variable k1 | ---/  |
+-------------+       |
| variable k2 | ------/
+-------------+
```

That is, you have three memory locations. The value of two of them (`k1` and `k2`) is the address of `j`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't print the addresses of `k1` and `k2`. You printed their value. And their value is *the address of* `j`.

If you *were* to print their addresses, like so (note the ampersand):

```
std::cout<<" k1 is "<< &k1 << " k2 is "<< &k2 << std::endl;
```

Those would be different.

Comment: i am a hw engineer. So from memory's point of view. I have three entries.
A  j
B  k1
C  k2

so both k1 and k2 values are A while you are saying B and C are different. Right?

Comment: @cxf54 - Correct. This is exactly what I'm saying.